# Selecionar modelo de acordo com a marca

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho a função que retorna todas as marcas cadastradas: (Com os campos ID e MARCA)

```
public function lista(){

        $lista = array();

        $n = 0;
        $db = new mysql();
        $exec = $db->executar("SELECT * FROM automovel_marca order by marca asc");
        while($data = $exec->fetch_object()){

            $lista[$n]['id'] = $data->id;
            $lista[$n]['marca'] = $data->marca;

            $n++;
        }
        return $lista;
}
```

E a função que retorna os modelos: (Com os campos ID, IDMARCA e MODELO)

```
public function lista(){

        $lista = array();

        $n = 0;
        $db = new mysql();
        $exec = $db->executar("SELECT * FROM automovel_modelo order by modelo asc");
        while($data = $exec->fetch_object()){

            $lista[$n]['id'] = $data->id;
            $lista[$n]['idmarca'] = $data->idmarca;
            $lista[$n]['modelo'] = $data->modelo;

            $n++;
        }
        return $lista;
}
```

Eu consegui puxar elas individualmente nos FORMS, o problema é que queria que o campo MODELO do FORM fosse relacionado ao campo MARCA, quando a pessoa selecionar a marca ele exiba todos os modelos referentes aquela marca.

A estrutura do DB está assim:

automovel_marca (id,marca)
automovel_modelo (id,idmarca,modelo) - neste caso o idmarca segue a relação do ID do automovel_marca

Answer (score 1):

Eu desconheço a estrutura das suas tabelas, mas vamos la basicamente alterariamos os dois locais abaixo no metodo lista do automovel_modelo:

```
public function lista($idmarca){

        $exec = $db->executar("SELECT * FROM automovel_modelo where idmarca = ".$idmarca." order by modelo asc");
```

Ai quando chamar o listar do automovel_modelo você passaria o parametro $idmarca.